# How to sum array members in Ruby excluding specific value?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2

I have an array of as given below.

For example:

```
array = [20%,*,30%, 10%]
```

I want to add the values except '*' using ruby, Please give me some clue for that

Comment: How did you end up with such an array in the first place and what have your tried? :)

Comment: "array.inject(:+)", But i think its not right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First below is not valid array.

```
array = [20%,*,30%, 10%]
```

If your array is

```
array = [ 20, 1, 1, 1, 30, 10 ]
```

If you want to sum array excluding 1 then use

```
array.reject { |value| value == 1 }.sum
=> 60
```

Comment: But i have an array as i have mentioned above

Comment: I am getting syntax error while initializing your array in console.

Comment: I have retrieved these values from "frameset" tag of HTML, It's a size of frames in frameset, so i want to check size of "*" in it

Comment: use array.reject { |x| x == "*" }.collect { |x| x.gsub("%", "").to_i }.sum

Comment: Thanks a lot Sounder, Your code works very well for my situation

Answer (score 0):

`array.except{ |a| a == * }.reduce(:+)`

Comment: It's not working. It shows me error as below "undefined method `except' for ["20%", "30%", "*", "10%"]:Array (NoMethodError)"

Comment: It should be `reject`, as in @soundar's answer.

Comment: oops, sure `reject` :) My bad